# Session-timeout funciona no local e dá erro na nuvem

Tags: java, timeout

Rodando a aplicação localmente o timeout funciona, mas quando coloco a aplicação na nuvem recebo esta mensagem de erro `The requested resource is not available` após o tempo esgotar.

O que estou fazendo de errado para minha aplicação dá erro apenas na nuvem e funcionar no local?

No arquivo web.xml o timeout está definido da seguinte maneira:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Na nuvem, após o timeout, esta tela é mostrada:
[image: Na nuvem, após o timeout, esta tela é mostrada]

Porém quando rodo a mesma aplicação localmente este erro não ocorre, o usuário é redirecionado á tela de login como deve ser feito.

Comment: Poste por favor as principais partes do código...